# Implementing Google mapV2 inside NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

The problem is i have three list in the slider which call three different fragment one of which contains google map. If i open it the first time , the map displa perfectly but for the second time when the tab is changed it throws error

```
   08-29 14:29:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(5543):  at savp.rebualo.tootle.Dashboard$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(Dashboard.java:153)
08-29 14:29:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(5543):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
08-29 14:29:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(5543):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
08-29 14:29:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(5543):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
08-29 14:29:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(5543):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1399)
08-29 14:29:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(5543):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
08-29 14:29:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(5543):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-29 14:29:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(5543):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-29 14:29:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(5543):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-29 14:29:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(5543):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
08-29 14:29:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(5543):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 14:29:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(5543):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-29 14:29:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(5543):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
08-29 14:29:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(5543):     at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
08-29 14:29:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(5543):     at   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-29 14:29:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(5543): Caused by:     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #29: Duplicate id    0x7f080084, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for  com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
```

This is the xml layout which i am infalting on click of a list this xml contains fragment for google map

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="false"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/source_l"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/source_l" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/source_d"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/source_d" />

 <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"            
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2.57" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is how i am initializing the google map

```
   public class AddRide extends Fragment {

 private GoogleMap googleMap;
 private   View rootView;

       public static AddRide newInstance() {
           AddRide fragment = new AddRide();  
         return fragment;  
       }  

       public AddRide() {  
       }  

       @Override  
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {  


           if (rootView != null) {
                ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();
                if (parent != null)
                    parent.removeView(rootView);
            }
            try {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_add_ride, container, false);
                initilizeMap();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                /* map is already there, just return view as it is  */
            }



           return rootView;  
       }  

       @Override  
       public void onAttach(Activity activity) {  
           super.onAttach(activity);  
           ((Dashboard) activity).onSectionAttached(1);  
       }  







        /**
         * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
         * */
        private void initilizeMap() {


            if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.map)).getMap();

                // check if map is created successfully or not
                if (googleMap == null) {
                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Text!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

ANd this is how i a adding the fragents fro into my activity.

public class Dashboard extends Activity implements
        NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

```
/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the
 * navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in
 * {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));














}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container,
                    PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)).commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
    case 1:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
        break;
    case 2:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
        break;
    case 3:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
        break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View rootView=null;
            switch(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
                case 1:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_searchride, container, false);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_add_ride, container, false);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_ride_notification, container, false);
                    break;

            }
            return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((Dashboard) activity).onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}

}
```

Comment: how you are adding fragment AddRide to view?

Comment: rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_add_ride, container, false); this is how i a adding from my dashboard activity whichi implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks

Comment: No, how are adding this fragment to activity? like fragmenttransaction.add or fragmenttransaction.replace? I want to see that 4-5 lines of code

Comment: i have updated my question. and added the whole class from where i am adding these fragments please have a look

Comment: Okay will see and try to suggest you some solution.

Comment: switch(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
                case 2:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_add_ride, container, false);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_ride_notification, container, false);  here you are inflating layout directly. I would suggest to create a instance of respective fragment like Fragment fragment = new AddRide() and use that

Comment: Actually i am very new to android. Can you please show me how to instance for eg for adding addride layout

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `android:id="@+id/map"` to

```
<fragment 
        android:id="@+id/myGoogleMap"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"            
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2.57" />
```

And in `initilizeMap`

```
googleMap = ((MapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myGoogleMap)).getMap();
```